# It is possible to decode and encode any file format to base64 (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, base64

I want to stream files from and to another computer using a 3rd party platform. This platform only allows for JSON formatted texts within its streams. I'm researching if its possible to transfer any type of file on this platform (e.g., jpeg, png, txt, exe, pdf, ...). I'd like to transfer a base64 decoded file in JSON format, as simple as:

```
{
"msg": "base64-string-YSToA0kR5Or1LnQ9hMYvHsgBshhnPGwmYsyZjJ9q",
"fileType": "png"
"fileId": "12414"
}
```

It is possible to decode any file format to base64, and encode it again to its original form at the target machine? I'm using JavaScript.

I tried looking for various NPM packages but I was unable to find a package to automate this process for any filetype. I only found a png to base64 decoder.

Comment: Yes, it is. You probably didn't find "any filetype" because  the filetype is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Base64 encodes byte values (256 bit numbers) into a string of printable characters in the Latin 1 page. It doesn't matter what encoding the bytes involve because base64 doesn't care.

Comment: Now, of course, the producer and consumer ends of your operation *do* have to know what the encoding is, but once you've got a base64 string it's just a string as far as JSON is concerned.